# Рамка вокруг блока, при фокусе на input без JS

Tags: css, style, focus

Как сделать рамку вокруг родительского блока, при фокусе на input. Чтобы рамка была вокруг "header-search-wrapper". Но только без JS, нужно на чистом CSS если возможно. С JS знаю как.

```
<div class="header-search-wrapper">
      <div class="header-search-content">
            <div class="h-s-w__input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search a product...">
            </div>
            <div class="h-s-w__submit"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.header-search-wrapper:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header-search-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="header-search-wrapper">
    <div class="header-search-content">
      <div class="h-s-w__input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search a product...">
      </div>
      <div class="h-s-w__submit"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Нужен всё обернуть в форму и воспользоваться псевдоклассом.
**Не поддерживается edge и IE**